# Is any error in my code in using evaluate in groovy?

Tags: groovy, evaluate

I'm setting value to a nested Map, the keys are all exist, here is my code:

```
def map = [a1:[a2:[a3:'a123']], b1:[b2:[b3_1:'b234', b3_2:'b345']], d1:'d1']
def name2 = "b1:::b2:::b3_1"
def data = "test"
def separator = ":::"

def names = name2.split(separator)

setValue(map, names, data)

def setValue(def map, def keys, def data) {
    tmpMap = map
    String str = 'map' 
    for (i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        str = str.concat('.'+ keys[i])
    }
    str = str.concat(" = '" + data + "'")

    evaluate(str)
}
```

the str content will be "map.b1.b2.b3_1 = 'test'"
I can manually run it and the map content is changed, but when I use evaluate, there has error of "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'b2' on null object", would you please tell me what's wrong with the code, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recurse approach:

```
def setValue(def map, List keys, def data) {
    return keys.size()>1 ? 
        setValue(map[keys[0]],keys.subList(1,keys.size()),data) : 
            map.put(keys[0],data)
}
```

Comment: Hi, your idea is good, but the result is not I want, I tried, the return value is b234

Comment: It returns the old value from map. And modifies the map. You can check it.

Comment: I am so sorry for so long time to respond, you are right, it worked and resolved my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is hard...

One method would be to use `Eval.x`, and pass in the map as the `x`:

```
def setValue(Map map, String[] keys, String data) {
    def command = "x.${keys.join('.')} = '$data'"
    Eval.x(map, command)
}
```

So here, command would be: `x.b1.b2.b3_1 = 'test'` and we evaluate it with `x` being the value of `map`

Another (more ugly) method is to use inject to walk the map until the last key, and then set the value of the last key of this returned object:

```
def setValue(Map map, String[] keys, String data) {
    keys[0..-2].inject(map) { a, b -> a."$b" }."${keys[-1]}" = data
}
```

You should be wary of evaluating code willy nilly though....

For example, the following input you may receive:

```
def name2 = "val = { -> println \"${System.properties.'user.name'}\" }.call(); def a"
```

Evaluates to the expression (for me):

```
x.val = { -> println "tim" }.call(); def a = 'test'
```

Which then prints the user name...  You can see how this could be adapted to download a file from the internet and put it on someone's machine...

If you can...  You should avoid this...  Or at least have stringent whitelists of what is allowed

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried your first method and it worked, as you said, it seemed a lit bit ugly, so I used recursive method to solve it,  thanks a lot of your warming help!